# Spring Batch: SingleItemPeekableItemReader not working some times

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to use `SingleItemPeekableItemReader` to read multiline data. This sometimes did not work and there is no error thrown. While debugging it just shows `reader.peek()` is null. What am i missing here?
Xml File snippet:

```
< bean id="itemReaderA" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
        ...
    < /bean> 
    < bean id="itemReaderB" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.SingleItemPeekableItemReader" scope="step">
        < property name="delegate" ref="itemReaderA"/>
    < /bean>
    < bean id="TransactionFileReader" class="<customReader class>" scope="step">
        < property name="delegate" ref="itemReaderB"/>
    < /bean>
```

Read method/Class

```
public class customReader implements ItemReader<ELCTransactionHeader>, ItemStream {
SingleItemPeekableItemReader<ElcHKTransactionFileDatabean> delegate;

public CustomBEan read() throws Exception, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    InputBEan line = null;
    InputBEan prevElement = null;
    boolean exit = false;       
    CustomBEan transactionObj = null;
    while (!exit && (line = (InputBEan) this.delegate.peek()) != null) {
        if ((prevElement == null ) || (prevElement != null && line.getInvoiceNumber().equals(prevElement.getInvoiceNumber()))) {
            System.out.println("Part of same txn or beginning of new txn");
            delegate.read();
            transactionObj = processLine(transactionObj , line);
            prevElement = line;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Different txn");
            exit = true;
        }

    }
    return transactionObj;
}
```

Comment: `not working some times` Can you isolate this behaviour to only the `SingleItemPeekableItemReader`? I see it used as a delegate in a custom reader.

Comment: Yes... I debugged this. N line which is returning null is this.delegate.peek().

Comment: ok great, in that case can you provide a unit test that "some times" fails? I will try to help on that.

Comment: Sorry, I did not have time to write unit test case as of now..But for me isue is resolved with below code n configuration. Just curious whether if we call peek method first makes difference?                                                                           < bean id="itemReaderA" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
        ...
    < /bean> 
   
    < bean id="TransactionFileReader" class="<customReader class>" scope="step">
        < property name="delegate" ref="itemReaderA"/>
    < /bean>

Comment: My Custom reader extends SingleItemPeekableItemReader and it calls read method first rather than calling peek method